# Flutter app not displaying on Emulator using Visual Studio Code, Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

Flutter App not displaying on Emulator using Visual Studio Code. I had setup all the file path and necessary extension on Android Studio (Flutter and Dart) and under Visual Studio code (Flutter and Dart extension, Android iOS emulator).

I am facing a problem, while I open emulator through Visual Studio Code to run Flutter app, Emulator open but only display normal. No displaying what I write code to display on visual studio code. I tried lots of stuffs from reinstalling and setup from scratch from file path to the extension on both Android Studio and Visual Studio. Here is the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

File path on environment variables:

[image]

where sometimes this error is shown on output.

[image]

What cause this problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: did u try to open emulator from Android Studio?

Comment: Please don't provide errors as a image

Comment: @Nguyenfamily Yes, I tried from Android studio and Android Studio also had problem while running flutter code automatically close the android studio. Even I successfully run my flutter app on emulator before factory reset of my laptop. This issue comes after factory reset and reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: @Nguyenfamily do i need to restall visual studio, android studio and file setup from scratch ?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot to see what's the error in your emulator.

Comment: No no, you open "VIRTUAL DEVICE MANAGER" from Android Studio, then you run a emulator. Can it be opened? I didn't mean that you run Flutter in Android Studio.

Comment: The advice to not supply errors as images is fine, but they still need to be supplied. Please convert them to formatted text when you have a moment.